# $f(a,b)\geq f(b,a)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to prove that
$$b+a^{1+\frac{b}{\ln(\frac{1}{b})}}(1-b)\geq a+b^{1+\frac{a}{\ln(\frac{1}{a})}}(1-a)$$
for $a\geq b$,  $a,b\in (0,1)$.

I have tried many things, such as derivatives. Even in the simpler case where $b=1/2$ and $1\geq a\geq 1/2$, I don't know how to do.
Any idea ?

Comment: Can you show that if $$f(x) = b+x^{1-\frac{b}{\ln b}}(1-b) - x + b^{1-\frac{x}{\ln x}}(1-x)$$ then $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge b$?

Comment: I have tried, but since your function vanish ar $x=1$ and $x=b$... (I guess there is a minus in front of the last term)